Can't seem to get plot to order by value -- am I using group_by() incorrectly? Or is it something else?
r plot of NIH grantee data
Hello!
I am an R beginner and really enjoying it. I was hoping to create a plot of National Institutes of Health (NIH) grants to research organizations in Massachusetts.
Everything works except for one thing -- my plot keeps getting ordered alphabetically by the organization's name, not by the total value of the grants received. Here's the code I'm using -- what am I doing wrong?
#let's filter out grants under $3M
mass_nih_big_grants <- filter(mass_NIH_data_2023_desc, TOTAL_COST >= 3000000) 

# let's group them by organization. 
# many organizations have more than 1 NIH grant, we want to see the total value
# of grants to an organization. 

mass_nih_big_grantees <- mass_nih_big_grants %>%
  group_by(ORG_NAME) 

# let's put that in descending order before we plot it
mass_nih_big_grantees_desc <- mass_nih_big_grantees[order(-mass_nih_big_grantees$TOTAL_COST),]
 
# do we have to group them again? 
mass_nih_big_grantees_desc %>% 
  group_by(ORG_NAME)
  
# let's plot what we've got. 
plot_mass_nih_big_grantees_desc <- ggplot(mass_nih_big_grantees_desc, aes(x=ORG_NAME, y=TOTAL_COST)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="dodgerblue") +
  coord_flip()
  
plot_mass_nih_big_grantees_desc + theme_light()  
# this works; it creates a plot but rearder is not working. It's sorting
# by org name descending (so, Z-A). 


Reordering the data will not reorder the plot and group_by() is for grouping data during summary calculations. The plot will be ordered by the order of the factor on the x axis. The default is ordering alphabetically, but you can either manually set the order using the levels parameter of the factor function or you can use the fct_reorder() function from forcats to order the factor according to the value of a function. The default function for ordering is the median, which works if the data are already summarized.
Compare these two plots where I reorder the factor in the second case.
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)
DF <- data.frame(Org = c("A","C","B"), Cost = c(4,3,6))
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Org, y = Cost)) + geom_col()


#Now reorder the Org by the Cost
ggplot(DF, aes(x = fct_reorder(Org, Cost), y = Cost)) + geom_col()


Created on 2024-11-16 with reprex v2.1.1
